# Proof verification: Prove, for every integer $x$, that the integers $3x+1$ and $5x+2$ are of opposite parity.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm doing some practice proofs from my textbook for a Methods of Proof final I have tomorrow, and I was wondering if someone could verify whether this proof works? If not, any suggestions on how it can be improved?

**Claim:** For every integer $x$, the integers $3x+1$ and $5x+2$ are of opposite parity.

**Proof:** Assume by contradiction that there exists an integer $x$ such that $3x+1$ and $5x+2$ are of the same parity.

*Case 1:* $3x+1$ and $5x+2$ are even.

Then $3x+1=2a, \exists a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $5x+2=2b,\exists b\in\mathbb{Z}$ by definition of even integers.

Adding the equations, 
$\begin{align}
3x+1+5x+2 &= 2a+2b \\
8x+3 &= 2a + 2b \\
8x+2+1&=2a+2b \\
2(4x+1)+1&=2(a+b)
\end{align}$

Since $4x+1,a+b\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $r=4x+1$ and $s=a+b$, $\exists r,s \in{Z}$.

$2r+1=2s$

$\to\leftarrow$

An odd integer cannot equal an even integer.

*Case 2:* $3x+1$ and $5x+2$ are odd.

Then $3x+1=2c+1, \exists c\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $5x+2=2d+1,\exists d\in\mathbb{Z}$ by definition of odd integers.

Adding the equations, 
$\begin{align}
3x+1+5x+2 &= 2c+1+2d+1 \\
8x+3 &= 2c + 2d+2 \\
8x+2+1&=2c+2d+2 \\
2(4x+1)+1&=2(c+d+1)
\end{align}$

Since $4x+1,c+d+1\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $t=4x+1$ and $u=c+d+1$, $\exists t,u \in{Z}$.

$2t+1=2u$

$\to\leftarrow$

An odd integer cannot equal an even integer.

$\therefore$ for every integer $x$, the integers $3x+1$ and $5x+2$ are of opposite parity. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: Numbers of the same parity differ by an even number but $(5x+2)-(3x+1)=2x+1$ is an odd number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems solid, the only improvement I would add is to properly conclude the case distinction as follows:

"Since the 2 cases cover all possible cases and since both of the cases lead to a contradiction we can conclude that for every integer $x$, the integers $3x+1$ and $5x+2$ are of opposite parity."

As lhf said in a comment, you could also show that the difference between the two integers is odd to get a shorter proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks right. However, since it looks that you are writing with extreme detail, it would be important to notice that you're using the fact that an integer can be both odd and even. I don't know if you already prove that, if you're allowed to use it or you're expected to prove it.

Comment: I think in our class we are allowed to assume that.